# Angular 6 Http Request giving wrong response

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, angular6, angular-httpclient

I am trying to make a HTTP Post request using angular 6's HttpClientModule.

The POST request I am making is as follows:

```
const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' })
    };

    httpOptions.headers = httpOptions.headers.append('Authorization', 'BasicAuth_Token');

    this._http.post(url, {
        s: '29'
    },httpOptions).subscribe(

      data => console.log('Success!',data),
      error => console.error('Error!', error)
    )
```

The Post request is successful and I am getting a response.
However I am not getting the response expected.
i.e

When I make the same POST request through AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    data: { s:'29'},

    success: function (data) {

        console.log("code - 1000", data);


      }
      else {
         console.log("code - 1001" , data);
      }
    },
    error: function (response) {
      console.log("Something went wrong", response);
    }
  });
```

I am getting a code - 1000 returned for the same POST data.
However I am getting a code - 1001 for POST in angular 6.

> Basically, for the same POST request - though the post is successful
>   in both ajax and Angular 6 , I am getting different responses for the
>   same data.
>
> If the post was unsuccesful , I could understand. However I am not
>   understanding how i am getting two different responses for the same
>   data i.e being sent to the API.